# Run executables in PowerShell without typing the file extension

Tags: powershell

I've been using PowerShell as my console on my desktop for a while now.  I'm still pretty new to it, but I'm comfortable.  I just got a laptop that I started using, but PowerShell acts differently when starting executables.  On my desktop, I can simply type

```
PS C:\> vim
```

On my laptop this doesn't work.  I need to type

```
PS C:\> vim.exe
```

Can anyone explain why I need to type the file extension on my new environment and how I can change that?  I know it's a minor issue, but it's grown to be quite an annoyance.

Here is my path and pathext which is the same one both my desktop and laptop:

```
PS C:\> $Env:PATH
C:\Program Files\ConEmu;C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;D:\Python34\;D:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Wi ndows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY;\D:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits \Tools\;D:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73;D:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\\bin;C:\Progra m Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr osoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\ bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;D:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin;D:\apache-ant-1.8.1\bin;D:\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1. 7.0_67\bin
PS C:\> $Env:PATHEXT
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.CPL
```

Comment: can you post one from the laptop and one from the desktop, so we can compare both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that it had nothing to do with my environment variables, execution policy, or any other settings.  My desktop is running PowerShell 4.0.  My laptop was running PowerShell 2.0.  After upgrading my laptop to PowerShell 4.0, executables now run without the need to type in the extension.

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing the solution. Could you please mark your question as answered ?

Comment: @Ob1lan: He can do that only after 2 days.